# jQuery load html specific div into webpage

Tags: jquery, load, slidedown

having a bit of a issue

got four links when clicked i want to to load in content from an external html page into a div called content which slides down and shows the content from the external html page, but I want to use the href from the links to load in specific div tags from the external html page.. I'm nearly there just missing the final part.. I cant seem to use my variable inside my jquery load statement..

this is what ive got so far..

```
    $("#services a").click(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
      console.log(href)
      $('#content').slideToggle(function(){
       $("#content").load("services.html" + href); 
      });
    return false;
    });
```

also if anyone could point me how to slide the content div back when selecting a different link and then show that content for that link.. would be great..

thanks guys..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing the href is correct and is the same as a selector, you're missing a space:

```
$("#services a").click(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     $('#content').slideToggle(function(){
         $("#content").load("services.html " + href); 
                      //                  ^^^ space needed here 
     });
     return false;
});
```

this is because the correct syntax for `load()` is

```
$("#content").load("services.html #IdOfelementToLoad"); 
//    ^^                ^^       ^         ^^
//  container         filename  space    selector for filter
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: white space is not legal in URL

Comment: It must be part of jQuery `.load()`, but there is supposed to be one here. @ABFORCE

Comment: thanks guys i wnat you use my variable as the filter can this be done :S

Comment: @AC88 - If the variable is a selector the above code should work, just add the space.