# How can i reload multiple div on ajax success ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to reload multiple div on ajax reload. Currently one div is loading properly, but i have to reload two more div on same event in pop-up.

### Code

```
   success:function(response){
            //alert(response);
            if(response) {
                $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                $(".loadOne").load(window.location + ".loadOne");
              $(".loadTwo").load(window.location + ".loadTwo");
            } else {
                alert('Check');     
           }
    }
```

currently `.reloadCOnt` loading properly but other two are not loading.

Comment: You are missing spaces in url for the last two, e.g: `window.location + " .loadOne"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".loadOne").load(window.location.href + " .loadOne");
              $(".loadTwo").load(window.location.href + " .loadTwo");
```

change code as above to fix the problem. added space before `.loadOne` and `.loadTwo`

Comment: replace window.location with window.location.href

Comment: @AyazShah you have to provide MCVE.  Myabe your element s are part of the first one you load and then not in DOM at time you are targeting them, who knows what you are doing wrong?... or maybe you didnt clear browser cache?!

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes your saying right. Actually `loadOne` is parent class of `ul li` and i want to reload `ul li`

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the spaces after the classes:

```
success:function(response){
  //alert(response);
  if(response) {
    $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
    $(".loadOne").load(window.location + " .loadOne");
    $(".loadTwo").load(window.location + " .loadTwo");
  } else {
    alert('Check');     
  }
}
```

Thanks to [jQuery load html specific div into webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673669/jquery-load-html-specific-div-into-webpage)